# Restrain access to chat in react-native using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know if it is possible to restrain access to a chat? I actually have two chat room and I want to restraint access to a specific number of users in one channel and let the other one for everyone. Can you make this using the firebase database?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: Read about 'Firebase rules'